# HashMap with key as Generic Type object returns false in containsKey

Tags: java

I have the following generic class which has the equals and hashcode method properly implemented

```
class Node<T> {
private T data;
private Node<T> previous;
private Node<T> next;

public Node(T data) {
    if (data != null) {
        this.data = data;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Null not allowed");
    }
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}

public Node<T> getPrevious() {
    return previous;
}

public void setPrevious(Node<T> previous) {
    this.previous = previous;
}

public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return data.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Node<T> that) {
    return this.data.equals(that.getData());
}}
```

This Node object is used as a key in a HashMap which keeps the count and its surrounding class is a different generic type.

```
class Struct<T> {
    private Map<Node<T>, Integer> counter = new HashMap<>();
    public boolean contains(Node<T> val) {
         return counter.containsKey(val);
    }
    public void add(Node<T> val) {
        if (contains(val)) {
             int count = counter.get(val);
             counter.put(val, ++count);
        } else {
             counter.put(val, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is called from my main method as

```
Struct<String> str = new Struct<String>();
str.add(new Node<String>("test1"));
System.out.println(str.contains(new Node<String>("test1")));
```

The println prints false even though the hashCode matches. Not sure where exactly I am going wrong in understanding the flow. I tried to debug the code by using loggers on hashCode and equals. But every time when I call contains key, the hashCode gets called which prints the same hashcode but the equals method is never called. Hence I do not think it's a duplicate of the linked issue.

**Update**
Node's equals method changed to the following which worked like a charm.

```
public boolean equals(Object that) {
    if (that == null) return false;
    if (that == this) return true;
    if (!(that instanceof Node))return false;
    Node thatVal = (Node) that;
    return this.data.equals(thatVal.getData());
}
```

Comment: `++counter.get(val)` is a compile error.

Comment: It absolutely is a duplicate. Read it more carefully.

Comment: Hello shmosel, I confirm that it was a duplicate. I just had to correct the Node's equals properly and then it worked like a charm. The problem was that I wasn't using an ide for this and hence was using println's to debug. The equals println wasn't getting triggered and hence the confusion. Thanks a ton.